# How to avoid "unidentified developer" error by gatekeeper

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-gatekeeper

As a developer of an app it could be quite a turn off if half of your users cannot open your app because they get following error.

[i know there is a workaround by going to sys preferences->security-> allow apps from "anywhere" but users of our apps are kids, they may not be in the best position to know how to do that]

[image]

What things I need to take care of in oder to avoid this warning, or to get apple developer identity?

This app has been published on App Store, so all the provisioning profiles and certificates are there. Now we want to put the app on our website, but before doing that we want to eliminate this gatekeeper hurdle.

[image]

In the screenshot above you can see that the right developer is selected while archiving.

Comment: I don't understand, if you have a developer certificate and are signing your application then shouldn't that be preventing Gatekeeper from presenting that warning? In other words, are you sure your app is actually being signed? The warning says "unknown developer" which, to me, sounds like your app is not signed.

Comment: The app is signed, as I said I published it to App store before archiving and putting it on website. After doing that some users complaied with this!!
I checked the settings (screenshot) and posted it again, the problem persisted.

Answer (score 4):

The signing identity used for App Store submissions and for independent publishing are different. The latter requires a Developer ID identity be used. See [Distributing Applications Outside the Mac App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html) for more information about the process.